# "Feather" library installation failing in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to download the [feather](https://github.com/wesm/feather) library but I am getting an error. I have already updated pip and setuptools but I am still getting errors. This is the output I get from PyCharm:

```
    Collecting feather
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/d1/073c848713d9987f48d0bc8415646760a069ef3ca80e9b45fdb6b4422133/feather-0.9.1dev.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\NICKAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\feather\distribute_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools
raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\NICKAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\feather\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
  File "C:\Users\NICKAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\feather\distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "C:\Users\NICKAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\feather\distribute_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
    to_dir, download_delay)
  File "C:\Users\NICKAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\feather\distribute_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
    src = urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NICKAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\feather\
```

=====================Update per Chris Hunt's Response==========================
I am actually receiving conflicting feedback as to whether I have installed feather-format. I receive this output from my anaconda command prompt:

```
    (base) C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>pip install feather-format
Requirement already satisfied: feather-format in c:\users\nick alexander\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyarrow>=0.4.0 in c:\users\nick alexander\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from feather-format) (0.12.0a0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14 in c:\users\nick alexander\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyarrow>=0.4.0->feather-format) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.0.0 in c:\users\nick alexander\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyarrow>=0.4.0->feather-format) (1.11.0)
```

Additionally, when I try to install feather-format on pycharm, I receive this error:

```
Collecting feather-format
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/55/940b97cc6f19a19f5dab9efef2f68a0ce43a7632f858b272391f0b851a7e/feather-format-0.4.0.tar.gz
Collecting pyarrow>=0.4.0 (from feather-format)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/b6/c4e63f8bdb175d2223df26ddf12e2a0ba3fa347890128b5f128cb3f72589/pyarrow-0.11.0.tar.gz (602kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.0.0 in c:\users\nick alexander\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pyarrow>=0.4.0->feather-format) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14 in c:\users\nick alexander\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pyarrow>=0.4.0->feather-format) (1.15.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyarrow
  Building wheel for pyarrow (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for pyarrow (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py" build_wheel C:\Users\NICKAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnf9ink_0:
  C:\Users\NICKAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-quyk7sl2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_scm\utils.py:118: UserWarning: 'git' was not found
    warnings.warn("%r was not found" % name)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\csv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\cuda.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\feather.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\filesystem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\formatting.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\hdfs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\ipc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\jvm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\orc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\pandas_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\parquet.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\plasma.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\serialization.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\types.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\_generated_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\deserialize_buffer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\pandas_examples.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_array.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_convert_builtin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_convert_pandas.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_csv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_cuda.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_cython.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_deprecations.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_feather.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_hdfs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_io.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_ipc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_jvm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_misc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_orc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_parquet.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_plasma.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_plasma_tf_op.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_scalars.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_schema.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_table.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_tensor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\test_types.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  copying pyarrow\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  running egg_info
  writing pyarrow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to pyarrow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to pyarrow.egg-info\entry_points.txt
  writing requirements to pyarrow.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to pyarrow.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'pyarrow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '#*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
  no previously-included directories found matching '.asv'
  writing manifest file 'pyarrow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying pyarrow\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\_csv.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\_cuda.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\_cuda.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\_orc.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\_orc.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\_parquet.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\_parquet.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\_plasma.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\array.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\benchmark.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\builder.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\error.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\feather.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\io-hdfs.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\io.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\ipc.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\lib.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\lib.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\lib_api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\memory.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\plasma_store -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\public-api.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\scalar.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\serialization.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\table.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  copying pyarrow\types.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\allocator.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\array.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\buffer.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\builder.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\compare.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\memory_pool.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\pretty_print.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\record_batch.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\status.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\table.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\table_builder.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\tensor.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\test-util.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\type.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\type_fwd.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\type_traits.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\visitor.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\visitor_inline.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\compute
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\compute\api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\compute
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\compute\context.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\compute
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\compute\kernel.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\compute
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\compute\kernels
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\compute\kernels\cast.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\compute\kernels
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\compute\kernels\hash.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\compute\kernels
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\io
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\io\api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\io
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\io\file.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\io
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\io\hdfs.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\io
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\io\interfaces.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\io
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\io\memory.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\io
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc\api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc\dictionary.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc\feather.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc\json.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc\message.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc\reader.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc\writer.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\ipc
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\api.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\arrow_to_pandas.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\arrow_to_python.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\builtin_convert.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\common.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\config.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\helpers.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\init.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\io.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\numpy_convert.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\numpy_interop.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\numpy_to_arrow.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\platform.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\pyarrow.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\python_to_arrow.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\python\type_traits.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\python
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\bit-stream-utils.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\bit-util.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\bpacking.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\compiler-util.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\compression.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\compression_brotli.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\compression_lz4.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\compression_snappy.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\compression_zlib.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\compression_zstd.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\cpu-info.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\decimal.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\hash-util.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\hash.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\key_value_metadata.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\logging.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\macros.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\parallel.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\rle-encoding.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\sse-util.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\stl.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\type_traits.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\variant.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\visibility.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util\variant
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\variant\optional.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util\variant
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\variant\recursive_wrapper.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util\variant
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\variant\variant_cast.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util\variant
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\variant\variant_io.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util\variant
  copying pyarrow\include\arrow\util\variant\variant_visitor.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\include\arrow\util\variant
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\includes
  copying pyarrow\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\includes
  copying pyarrow\includes\common.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\includes
  copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\includes
  copying pyarrow\includes\libarrow_cuda.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\includes
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tensorflow
  copying pyarrow\tensorflow\plasma_op.cc -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tensorflow
  copying pyarrow\tests\pyarrow_cython_example.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\README.md -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.emptyFile.jsn.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.emptyFile.orc -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.test1.jsn.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.test1.orc -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.testDate1900.jsn.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\TestOrcFile.testDate1900.orc -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\decimal.jsn.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\orc\decimal.orc -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\orc
  creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.all-named-index.parquet -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.column-metadata-handling.parquet -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.parquet -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
  copying pyarrow\tests\data\parquet\v0.7.1.some-named-index.parquet -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pyarrow\tests\data\parquet
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

  running build_ext
  creating build\temp.win32-3.6
  creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 197, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 141, in build_wheel
      metadata_directory)
    File "C:\Users\NICKAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-quyk7sl2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in build_wheel
      _run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\NICKAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-quyk7sl2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 85, in _run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 586, in <module>
      url="https://arrow.apache.org/"
    File "C:\Users\NICKAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-quyk7sl2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\NICKAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-quyk7sl2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 188, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Nick Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "setup.py", line 88, in run
      self._run_cmake()
    File "setup.py", line 248, in _run_cmake
      raise RuntimeError('Not supported on 32-bit Windows')
  RuntimeError: Not supported on 32-bit Windows

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow

  Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Could not build wheels for {} which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

So it looks like I simply need to update my interpreter to 64 bits?

Comment: Maybe this issue will help you (https://github.com/wesm/feather/issues/322)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're trying to install [feather](https://github.com/wesm/feather) (the package for "Feather: fast, interoperable binary data frame storage" then you should execute `pip install feather-format`. The PyPI [feather](https://pypi.org/project/feather/) package is different and appears to only be for Python 2.x.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for your response. I have updated my question to address your answer.

Comment: @njalex22 to answer your question - yes you will need to update your Python to the 64bit version.

Comment: And feather-format will allow me to extract data from feather files?

Comment: @njalex22, if you have other questions or issues outside the scope of your original question, please search StackOverflow or create a new question. Doing it this way makes it easier for others to find existing questions and get help.

Comment: @njalex22 Yes, that is correct, `feather-format` (counter-intuitively) is the library for saving and loading feather files. Contrary to other comments I see zero harm in small meta-questions that provide helpful and relevant information to users in a convenient location. @Chris Hunt `feather-format` and its dependencies are fully compatible with python 3.7.2 64-bit. Note feather-format has one dependency (I think `pyarrow`?) that requires 64-bit to install from pip.

Comment: @OrangeSherbet, the Python 2.x compatibility comment was not directed at `feather-format` - I have edited the answer to hopefully be more clear.